# Create only the records that doesnt exist in a table

Tags: mysql

```
USE Table;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/file.csv' 
INTO TABLE TABLE1 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
(, Field1, Field2, Field3);
```

My question is, will all the records be skipped that exist previously on the table and will only the records be created that didn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, your table has to have a primary key or an unique index. And the data you import, has to insert data into this column also. Then existing rows can be identified. And you have to add the `IGNORE` keyword.
Read more about `IGNORE` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/file.csv' 
IGNORE
INTO TABLE TABLE1 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
(Field1, Field2, Field3);
```

From the manual:

```
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE 'file_name'
    [REPLACE | IGNORE] /*don't confuse this one...*/
    INTO TABLE tbl_name
    [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
        [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
        [ESCAPED BY 'char']
    ]
    [LINES
        [STARTING BY 'string']
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    ]
    [IGNORE number LINES] /*...with this one*/
    [(col_name_or_user_var,...)]
    [SET col_name = expr,...]
```